# Output of a column to only have two decimal numbers?

Tags: sql-server, web-applications

I'm showing the query output on a default ViewGrid on a VB.NET web application and some of the output values give me 4 decimal values while I only need two decimal values do to the result for showing a currency.

How can I specify in the query to only show me a maximum of two decimal values for the values of `D.ORIG_PRC` and `D.DISC_AMT`?

**My Query**

```
 SELECT H.Emp_ID, H.Cust_ID, H.Rgst_ID, D.TRAN_LN_NUM, D.DISC_CD, D.AUTH_EMP_ID, D.ORIG_PRC, D.DISC_AMT, D.DISC_PCT, D.GL_ACCT_ID
 FROM Transaction_Header H 
 INNER Join LN_Detail L ON (H.Str_ID = L.Str_ID And H.Rgst_ID = L.Rgst_ID And H.Tran_ID = L.Tran_ID)
 INNER Join LN_Discount D ON (L.Str_ID = D.Str_ID And L.Rgst_ID = D.Rgst_ID And L.Tran_ID = D.Tran_ID And L.Tran_LN_Num = D.Tran_LN_Num)  
 WHERE(H.Str_ID = @Str_ID)
    And (H.Tran_ID = @Tran_ID)
    And ((H.Rgst_ID = @Rgst_ID) Or (@Rgst_ID Is NULL Or @Rgst_ID = ''))
```

Comment: `convert(decimal(9,2),MyColumn)`

Comment: Or in VB `.ToString(#,###.00)`

Comment: Beware that `convert(decimal(9,2),MyColumn)` is limited to nine digits total - two after the decimal place, seven before. If you're dealing with large numbers you may wish to increase that to something like `convert(decimal(18,2),MyColumn)` or more.